# How can i convert string to variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a function in which i am receiving a string values .

Based on the value i want to create a variable.

```
Template<typename T>
void func( std::string str , T value )
{
    if( str == "int" )
     {
          int val = value;

     }

     if( str == "double" )
     {
          double val = value;

     }

    if( str == "string" )
     {
          std:string val = value;

     }    
}
```

is it possible to automate this function , instead of having lot of if conditions ?

Comment: `template <typename T> void func(T value) { std::cout << value; }` ?

Comment: @L.F i want to convert string value to a variable , std::cout is just for reference.

Comment: Your code is a bit strange, `T` is a type known at compile time, but `str` is known at run time. What happens if they don't match?

Comment: @john based upon str value i want to create a variable.

Comment: @suman That doesn't answer my question. Suppose you have `func("str", 123);`? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Use a template<class S, class T> fn(T val){...}; if(str=="int") fn<int, T>(value); if(str=="double") fn<double, T>(value);  if(str=="string") fn<std::string, T>(value);

Answer (score 1):

You have done great, created a `template function` to check the variable type, and then create a variable of that type.

For this, c++11 has introduced the `auto`, for variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer. [c++ auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <string> // std::string
#include <typeinfo> // to check type info

template <typename T>
void func(T value){
    auto val = value; // correctly auto deduced type by compiler(since c++11).

    std::cout << typeid(val).name() << std::endl; // check the auto deduced type info
}

int main(){

    // try
    func(12); // output-> i
    func(12.3); // output -> d
    func("Hello world");

    return 0;
}
```